# Highcharts function not covered with unit tests with Karma + Jasmine

Tags: highcharts, karma-jasmine, angular8

Since I'm trying to use your Highcharts package, I'm facing an issue when unit testing the component that use Highcharts function.

Here is my context:

I have a component (the only one) that use Highcharts. In the Web client, When I run unit test on this component, chart function legendItemClick not getting covered.

Code below are the Javascript transpilled code. Here is my original typescript file:

```
let dsCapacityChartOptions = {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    spacing: [0, 10, 2, 10],
    margin: [-10, 0, 30, 0]
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      shadow: false,
      colors: ['#3E7BBF', '#CBCBCB', '#92B2D9'],
      point: {
        events: {
          legendItemClick: function () {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false
        },
        inactive: {
          opacity: 1
       }
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    outside: true,
    style: {
      color: '#000000',
      opacity: 1,
      fontSize: '12px',
      fontFamily: 'Metropolis,Avenir Next,Helvetica Neue,Arial,sans-serif'
    },
    formatter:
      function () {
        return '<b>' + this.point.x + '</b>: ' + this.point.formattedCapacity + " (" + this.percentage.toFixed(2) + "%)";
      }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: this.labelsObj["vsc.portlet.dsCapacity.label"],
    size: '80%',
    innerSize: '70%',
    showInLegend: true,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    data: []

  }],
  legend: {
    labelFormatter: function () {
      return this.x + ": " + this.formattedCapacity;
    },
    align: 'center',
    layout: 'vertical',
    itemStyle: {
      color: '#454545',
      fontWeight: '500',
      fontSize: '12px',
      fontFamily: 'Metropolis,Avenir Next,Helvetica Neue,Arial,sans-serif'
    },
    itemHoverStyle: {
      color: '#454545',
      cursor: 'default'
    }
  },
  exporting: { enabled: false }
};
```

Here is what I'm doing to make the unit tests works-

```
it('should call legendItemClick', () => {
  let spy = spyOn(component.dsCapacityChartOptions.plotOptions.pie.point.events, 'legendItemClick')
  component.dsCapacityChartOptions.plotOptions.pie.point.events.legendItemClick();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
})
```

Highcharts function not covered with unit tests with Karma + Jasmine

Please find below snippet of code coverage-
[Code coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVlrV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your unit test doesn't make sense. You explicitly invoke a function and test if it was  really called. In your case, `legendItemClick` returns a value, hence you should check the result of the call. There's no need to use a `spy`.

The test would then look simple as follows:

```
it('#legendItemClick should return false', () => {
  const result = component.dsCapacityChartOptions.plotOptions.pie.point.events.legendItemClick();
  expect(result).toBe(false);
})
```